# how to change tester in test case (TFS API)

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I'm trying to change tester of the test case in tfs api

in test-case manager i see this testers: https://gyazo.com/03adc434225c4c5541f602bc954feaed

i try to create and add TestPointAssignment with this tester:

```
IdAndName idAndName = new IdAndName(testSuite.Id, testSuite.Title);
var assignment = testSuite.CreateTestPointAssignment(testCase.Id, idAndName, Tester);
testSuite.AssignTestPoints(new List<ITestPointAssignment>() { assignment });
```

but nothing changes and remains the same tester.

how can i change tester in test-case with tfs api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a Tester of a Test Case using TFS API, you could try the following code snippet:

```
string teamProjectName = "TeamProjectName";
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://serverName:8080/tfs/MyCollection"));
 ITestManagementService testService = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
ITestManagementTeamProject teamProject = testService.GetTeamProject(teamProjectName);
//get test point of a test case
ITestPlan tplan = teamProject.TestPlans.Find(testplanid);
ITestPoint point = tplan.QueryTestPoints("SELECT * FROM TestPoint WHERE TestCaseID = Testcaseid").FirstOrDefault();

IIdentityManagementService ims = tfsCollection.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
TeamFoundationIdentity tester = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.DisplayName, "Mike", MembershipQuery.Direct, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
//change tester for testcase
point.AssignedTo = tester;
point.Save();
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but how can i add ITestPoint if `tplan.QueryTestPoints("SELECT * FROM TestPoint WHERE TestCaseID = Testcaseid").FirstOrDefault()` return `null`?

Comment: If it returns null, that means it could not find that test case with the TestCaseId you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with idAndName.

`CreateTestPointAssignment` expects a list of `ITestPointAssignment` objects, where each object contains:

- The Test Case Id
- The **Configuration**
- The TeamFoundationIdentity (user)

I believe it's failing because you're specifying the suite id and name, not a configuration id and name.

As you're probably aware, each tester gets assigned a *Test Point*, which is the intersection of a test case and a configuration. In MTM, you can see your configurations in *Organize* -> *Test Configuration Manager*. You'll see the ID and Name there, though in code, you'll probably want to query that list through the suite's `DefaultConfigurations` property. (Note that if it's empty, it means it's inheriting configurations from its parent or ancestor, and you may have to get the values from there.)